# Regex to remove comments from SQL Query String using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I managed to find the regex for handling /* */ cases but it doesn't work well for -- cases. How can I change my regex to fix this?

```
var s = `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
/* first line of comment
   second line of comment */
   -- remove this comment too
   SELECT * FROM TABLE_B`;

var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)|(--[^*]*)/g, '');
/*
Expected:

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
*/
console.log(stringWithoutComments);
```

Thank you

https://jsfiddle.net/8fuz7sxd/1/

Comment: And what about a comment appearing inside a string literal? And other edge cases. You should really use an SQL parser for this, skip all the comments and then write back the resulting SQL. And what about `OR/* comment */DER`?

Comment: Remember: whenever you ask for a regex, a regex is usually not the correct solution.

Comment: @RolandIllig What would be the better potential solution?

Comment: As I said: use a proper SQL parser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var s = `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
/* first line of comment
   second line of comment */
   -- remove this comment too
   SELECT * FROM TABLE_B`;

var stringWithoutComments = s.replace(/(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)|(--[^.].*)/gm, '');
/*
Expected:

SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
*/
console.log(stringWithoutComments);

// without linebreak
stringWithoutComments = stringWithoutComments.replace(/^\s*\n/gm, "")
console.log(stringWithoutComments);


// without whitespace
stringWithoutComments = stringWithoutComments.replace(/^\s+/gm, "")
console.log(stringWithoutComments);
```

Comment: This does not work if the comment contains "*" in it.

Comment: This will break when `/*` or `--` appear in strings.