# Remove Comments from MYSQL File

Tags: javascript, regex

I am aware of this: [Regex to remove comments from SQL Query String using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814265/regex-to-remove-comments-from-sql-query-string-using-javascript)

Which I thought as the answer, but that still leaves the newline which I also need to remove:

```
sql = `HELLO 1
-- comments 1
HELLO 2
-- comments 2
HELLO3
`;

sql.replace(/.*--.*/g,'');
```

But this still leaves spaces and does not remove the whole line:

```
HELLO 1

HELLO 2

HELLO3
```

What I am looking for is this:

```
HELLO 1
HELLO 2
HELLO3
```

How can I achieve this in the regex without executing a second replace to replace blank lines ?

Comment: Try this `\n.*--.*`

Comment: Append ```\r?\n|\r``` to your regex to remove newlines ... have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Comment: Thanks, but cannot remove newlines as they might be valid, the regex need to match the line starting with -- and remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

`\n(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)|\n(--[^.].*)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LgjXKY/2)

Code:

```
sql = `HELLO 1
-- comments 1
HELLO 2
-- comments 2
HELLO3
`;

sql.replace(/\n(\/\*[^*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[^*]*)|\n(--[^.].*)/g,'');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, yes that did it